# getting error when accessing a java variable (via java method) using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, liveconnect

For some reason I can't get the variable to be read using JavaScript.

I am using an applet and the errors I get in my Chrome console is:

> Uncaught Error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.processor_identifer")
>
> Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.

Access code:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Javascript call Applet example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function callSerial() {
            var foo = systemInfo.getSerial();
            console.log(foo);
        }
      </script>
      <center>
          <form>
              <input type="button" value="Call Applet" onclick="callSerial();"/>
          </form>
          <br/><br/>

          <applet id="systemInfo" code="systeminfo.class" width="300" height="50"></applet>

      </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by via java method using java script

Comment: Have you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html)? Have you set "MAYSCRIPT"? On second thoughts this look like a permissions issue - is your applet signed?

Comment: @hop: I am using a java method in my applet file `public String Serial() {.....` and then using javascript to read this method (the method returns a string, the string that I want to read)

Comment: @bmorris591: what do you mean signed (most probably not)? how to do this

Comment: Why does the edit remove the Java code from the link ?

Comment: what do you mean? which link?

Comment: The github link you put originally in the post

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1) In your applet code, mention **code=** fully qualified class name. **Ie: package.class**

2) If your java class is trying to access some file from the local client file system then you will have to get your applet signed like this >> http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm

Regards,